# Angular HTTP Interceptor make requests one after another

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

**Problem**: Angular app I'm working with is pretty complicated in terms of construction. There is case with many instances of same component with different data input in same place (parent component), every component is **different chart** displayed in the app, something like: 
 `<sample-component [data]='data1> </sample-component> 
 <sample-component [data]='data2> </sample-component>
<sample-component [data]='data3> </sample-component>
... so on` 
 so this data is processed differently in every case and based on that every component is making same call to same API endpoint. So **problem is** the call is executed suddenly multiple times from multiple component instances which is killing the app performance or server with too many requests. 
 
**Example Solution:** I was thinking about Angular HTTP Interceptor and how with this tool I can catch every request and make it execute when previous one is resolved, so they would fire one by one. So far I implemented the Interceptor and I was able to access every HTTP Event or Request from the Observable, but from this point I got no clue how or if it's possible to move on with "delaying" them. (I'm still learning RxJs and Angular related things)

I'm also not sure if this is legit solution or there is another practise - probably better solution will be to build more optimized app. Also heard about such mechanism like caching HTTP requests. If those requests can't be handled properly at a "global" level I would have to dive into app to rebuild its structure I guess. Any advices or tips how to deal with such thing? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider making a request **once** in a **smart component** and then pass the data to multiple `sample-component`instances(**dumb components**) ?

Comment: Yes this is another solution, but before touching logic of the components and services and rebuilding it I want to try handling it at higher level so component and service responsible for request stay untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You can use operators like **shareReplay** to cache your http calls to return  will always the last emitted value and make late late subscribers access it without executing the call again:

```
...
.pipe(
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
 )
```

Comment: Where would you place this more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to solve this is to use a facade service.

#### chart.facade.ts

```js
chartData$: Observable<any>;

loadChartData () {
 this.chartData$ = this.http.get(...).pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true }));
}
```

#### parent.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit () {
 this.charFacade.loadChartData();
}
```

Now I'd say it depends on how you organize things, but as far as I understand, every `sample-component` will make an http call on its own.

#### sample.component.ts

```js
// chartFacade.chartData$ - instantiated in `parent` component
this.chartData$ = this.chartFacade.chartData$;

constructor (private chartFacade: ChartFacade) { }
```

Every time you do `chartData$ | async` in your `sample` component's template, the 
 http call should be made only once and the result should be retrieved from the `ReplaySubject`'s cache.

When `refCount === true`, if there are no active subscriptions(e.g: every `sample` component got destroyed), the `ReplaySubject` used by `shareReplay` will be thrown away, meaning that when those components are loaded again, there will occur an http call, whose result will be stored by the new `ReplaySubject`.

[Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eq8n7iuHxQo) a talk on Facades.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataService to wrap your http calls and handle caching there. With a combination of `BehaviorSubject` and `httpClient`

```
_cache=new BehaviorSubject(null)
getData(){
   if(!this._cache.value){ 
       http.get(url).subscribe(this._cache)
   return this._cache.pipe(filter(data=>data),first())
}
invalidateCache(){ this._cache.next(null);)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit overengineered, but it works.

```js
export class Deferred<T> {
  public readonly promise: Promise<T>;
  private resolveFn!: (value: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void;
  private rejectFn!: (reason?: unknown) => void;
  private _resolved = false;
  public get resolved(): boolean {
    return this._resolved;
  }
  public _rejected = false;
  public get rejected(): boolean {
    return this._rejected;
  }
  public get settled(): boolean {
    return this.resolved || this.rejected;
  }

  public constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject): void => {
      this.resolveFn = resolve;
      this.rejectFn = reject;
    });
  }

  public reject(reason?: unknown): void {
    this._rejected = true;
    this.rejectFn(reason);
  }

  public resolve(param: T): void {
    this._resolved = true;
    this.resolveFn(param);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private readonly requestWaitTimeout = 1000;
  private readonly floodgateTimeout = 3000;
  private readyToSendAnotherRequest: Promise<undefined> =
    Promise.resolve(undefined);
  private requestNumber = 0;

  constructor(private readonly messageService: MessageService) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const thisRequestNumber = this.requestNumber;
    ++this.requestNumber;
    const requestUrl = req.urlWithParams;
    this.messageService.log(
      `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} was created`
    );
    return new Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>>(
      (subscriber: Subscriber<HttpEvent<unknown>>): Unsubscribable => {
        this.messageService.log(
          `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} was subscribed to`
        );
        const requestSentOrTimedOutDeferred = new Deferred<undefined>();
        const requestWaitedTooLongDeferred = new Deferred<undefined>();
        const resultingPromise = Promise.any([
          this.readyToSendAnotherRequest,
          requestWaitedTooLongDeferred.promise,
        ]);
        this.readyToSendAnotherRequest = requestSentOrTimedOutDeferred.promise;
        const floodgateTimeoutId = Number(
          setTimeout((): void => {
            this.messageService.error(
              `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} has wated in queue for too long, next request is allowed to be sent in parallel with this one`
            );
            requestWaitedTooLongDeferred.resolve(undefined);
          }, this.floodgateTimeout)
        );

        const timeoutId: {
          id: number | undefined;
        } = { id: undefined };

        const resolveDeferred = (): void => {
          clearTimeout(timeoutId.id);
          clearTimeout(floodgateTimeoutId);
          if (!requestSentOrTimedOutDeferred.settled) {
            this.messageService.log(
              `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} was resolved`
            );
            requestSentOrTimedOutDeferred.resolve(undefined);
          }
        };
        const result = from(resultingPromise).pipe(
          tap({
            complete: (): void => {
              timeoutId.id = Number(
                setTimeout((): void => {
                  this.messageService.error(
                    `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} took too long to process, next request is allowed to be sent in parallel with this one`
                  );
                  resolveDeferred();
                }, this.requestWaitTimeout)
              );
            },
          }),
          switchMap((): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> => {
            this.messageService.log(
              `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} is ready to be sent`
            );
            return next.handle(req);
          }),
          tap({
            next: (event: HttpEvent<unknown>): void => {
              this.messageService.log(
                `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} yielded next value`,
                event
              );
              if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                resolveDeferred();
              }
            },
            error: (err: unknown): void => {
              this.messageService.error(
                `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} resulted in failure`,
                err
              );
              resolveDeferred();
            },
            complete: (): void => {
              this.messageService.log(
                `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} completed`
              );
              resolveDeferred();
            },
          })
        );
        result.subscribe(subscriber);
        return {
          unsubscribe: (): void => {
            this.messageService.log(
              `Request ${thisRequestNumber} ${requestUrl} was unsubscribed from`
            );
            resolveDeferred();
          },
        };
      }
    );
  }
}
```

In app.module.ts add into providers:

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [MessageService],
    },
]
```

You can use `console.error` or `console.log` instead of custom `MessageService` or just remove all logging entirely. In that case, remove all mentions of `MessageService` and replace them with necessary logging calls. Also, remove `deps` from `providers` entry.

The interceptor works like this:

- Wraps each call to Angular's HttpClient in a custom Observable.
- When someone subscribes to that observable, the magic happens. We'll wait until previous request was resolved or we've been waiting for the previous request to resolve for too long (3 seconds, see `floodgateTimeout`). The request is considered resolved, if:

  - A response with a status code was received from the server (we don't wait for the entire body of the response to be received from the server, only the status code).
  - An error happened (e.g. no internet connection or wrong URL address).
  - A response took too much time to resolve (1 second, see `requestWaitTimeout`).
  - The request was unsubscribed from (helps to deal with those pesky clients that ask us to create an HTTP request but don't wait for the server to respond).